# Start function only when active class image is loaded - Twitter Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using Twitter Bootstrap Carousel with an Image + Audio file in each slide, using the HTML img and audio tags respectively.

Function 1 stops playing audio file in case the user changes the slides midway. Function 2 plays the audio file if one exists. Function 3 ensures that if there is no user interaction, the slide auto-changes after the audio ends.

**The problem:** On low bandwidth connections, the audio sometimes starts playing even before the complete image is loaded.

**What I have tried:** document.ready() is already being used. I don't want to use window.load before otherwise the user might have to wait for all the slideshows (could be over 50 in number) to load. If I try using $(".active img").load( function() {  }); it doesn't work at all. I have tried replacing $(".active img") with $("img") as well - same result.

**What is required:** A function which plays the audio only after the image (and audio) with the class "active" have been loaded.

Here's the code.

Some helpful info - The id of the div where the carousal images are kept = #carousel-example-generic; on('slide.bs.carousel') function runs when a slide transition is completed; play/pause etc are default methods given by HTML

```
     $(document).ready(function(){    
        // Stop audio if slide changes
        $(function(){
                $('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
                    if($(".active audio").length) {
                        $(".active audio")[0].pause();
                        $(".active audio")[0].currentTime = 0;}
                });
            });

         $(function(
         $('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
         if($(".active audio").length){
            $(".active audio")[0].play();
            }
            else{
            //if no audio move to next slide.
            setTimeout(function() {$('#carousel-example-generic').carousel('next');},500);
            console.log("No Audio");}
          });
        });


        //As the audio ends --> move to next slide with some delay.

        $("audio").bind("ended", function(){ 
        setTimeout(function(){
              $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel('next');}, 200);
              console.log("Audio ended");
    });
    }
```

Update: Even after successfully implementing the .load function, the audio starts before the image loads. I have tried using both .load(function(){} and $(".active img").on("load", function(){}). None of them seem to wait for the image to actually load.

I am currently using document.readyState but that has a problem - it waits for all the images to load before going ahead. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt is good if the class .active is applied to an img's ancestor tag. If the class .active is for the img tag itself, you should try:

```
$("img.active").load()
```

or just

```
$(".active").load()
```

In this second case you must make sure that no other tag has this class.

However I suggest you to preload the first 3/4 images and start the slide show with those already available; then, while user is enjoying the first slidehow images, load the remaining images via AJAX.

Comment: You could try to bind the _load_ event to the new inserted images throuh the .bind jQuery function.
Probably the load event is not binded for the elements that are inserted after the page first loading.